# link to anchor from URL using react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

I have a FAQ page i have created with many questions and answers in the form of

```
<div>
    <h4 id="anchor-name">question</h4>
    <p>answer</p>
</div>
```

This works as expected if i have a button or clickable link in the form of

```
<a href="#anchor-name">Click here to go to anchor</a>
```

which takes me directly to my question with that id (expected behaviour)
The problem is when i try to access this from a URL from another tab by doing something like

```
https://my-app-url/#/FAQ/#anchor-name
```

it redirects me to my FAQ page but not to my question. Instead, it just loads the FAQ and stays on the top.

Some context:

- frontend is in react
- the first # in the url `https://my-app-url/#/FAQ/#anchor-name` is mandatory. Apparently if i just go with `https://my-app-url/FAQ/#anchor-name` it never loads the page
- I have tried enclosing the `<div>` tags and the `<h4>` tags by an `<a>` tag but it didn't work. In those cases what i did was

```
<div>
    <a href="#anchor-name">
      <h4 id="anchor-name">question</h4>
      <p>answer</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

What i wish to know and cannot seem to find it by doing research a lot is:

1. Is it possible to access this anchor via URL from an external link by using react-router library?
2. Could it be that by using react the html way to anchor is not working as expected?
3. Is my first # in the URL interfering with the anchor linking feature?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need that last `/` right before the `#anchor-tag`.

so the URL would be:

```
https://my-app-url/#/FAQ#anchor-name
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Unfortunately i have already tried that and it has not worked. Is there any other thing i might have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might be interested, I fixed this issue. The problem was fixed by replacing HashHistory with BrowserHistory. With HashHistory, the URL gets an # that interferes with anchors. By using BrowserHistory, that # is never there so the issue is gone. Hopes this helps.